# Drawing multiple rectangles chokes my WPF app

Tags: c#, wpf

I am working in my own editor for making WPF forms. My issue is that I am having the worst time selecting multiple controls (buttons, labels, etc) and dragging them smoothly across the main window. My application chokes when I try to drag, oh say, 20 selected buttons at the same time.

I found that the culprit is the fact that I am drawing multiple rectangles for each object as they are being dragged and this function is being called in the MouseMove event.

```
void ControlObjectControl_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{    
   if (newPosition != oldPosition)
   {          
      DragSelection(newPosition); 
   }
}

private void DragSelection(Point newPosition)
{


    foreach (FrameworkElement item in designer.SelectionService.CurrentSelection)
       {
        if (item is ObjectControl)
            (item as ObjectControl).m_ParentControlObject.Position = new System.Drawing.Rectangle() { X = X, Y = Y, Width = (int)item.Width, Height = (int)item.Height }; 
          //..There's code that calculates the item's position and dimensions       
    }

}
```

How do I make it to where it only draws the rectangle once and I am still able to see my selected object(s) move smoothly when I drag them?

Comment: WPF uses DirectX, there's not a ton you can do without digging really deep. You might try grabbing your max bounds for all selected controls on mousedown, creating a transparent panel, adding all selected controls to that, and then moving the panel instead of each control, and then dumping them back on the form on mouseup. I'm honestly not familiar with how VS/others do it, but that's probably where I'd start (unless someone has a built-in solution). It might make snapping difficult/logic intensive though.

Comment: @Aaron yes I see. I tried using a dispatcher and made the code run in the background but that just made the dragging feature weird. I'm gonna look into this issue further. Thank you for being my first response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did something similar in my application except I used a `TranslateTransform` to move my elements. Each "frame" (every mouse move) that I was dragging, I got the position of the mouse and compared that to the previous position of the mouse. I would then set a new `TranslateTransform` X/Y values equal to the X/Y mouse position change and then would give that to the `RenderTransform` of each object I wanted to move. Something like:

```
void ControlObjectControl_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{    
   if (dragging)
   {  
      // Get the change in Location        
      mouseLocation = Mouse.GetPosition();
      Point deltaLocation = mouseLocation - previousLocation;

      // Make a new transform
      TranslateTransform transform = new TranslateTransform();
      transform.X = deltaLocation.X;
      transform.Y = deltaLocation.Y;

      // Apply the transform
      // foreach thing
      thing.RenderTransform = transform;

      // set previous location
      previousLocation = mouseLocation;
   }
}
```

Now your objects only get drawn once and only their positions get changed. Hope this helps